# this code works but there are 2 cases that it doesnt work

Tags: python

**this code doesnt pass 2 hidden tests **

```
inputs = input()
simulation_days = int(inputs.split(" ")[0])
initial_bone_mass = float(inputs.split(" ")[1])
initial_muscle_mass = float(inputs.split(" ")[2])

final_muscle_mass = initial_muscle_mass
final_bone_mass = initial_bone_mass

for day in range(simulation_days):
    final_muscle_mass *= (1 - 0.02) 
    final_bone_mass *= (1 - 0.015)  
    final_bone_mass += 0.02 * final_muscle_mass  
    final_muscle_mass -= 0.02 * final_muscle_mass  

print(f"Final Muscle Mass: {final_muscle_mass:.2f} kg and Final Bone Mass: {final_bone_mass:.2f} kg")
```

**this is the instructions:**

> Gravity in space - a simulation of the effects on the human body
> (challenging question)
>
> Many believe that there is no gravity in space, but space also has gravity. So why are astronauts floating in space?
>
> Actually on the space station the astronauts are in constant free fall, an object that is in free fall will be in a state of weightlessness, or microgravity. Although levitation sounds like real fun, the human body is not built for sub-gravity conditions and many astronauts suffer from balance problems, damage to the heart muscles, loss of bone mass and vision problems. The space station or space shuttle is in a state of free fall towards the Earth. The International Space Station orbits the Earth at an altitude of about 400 kilometers.
>
> Following the stay on the station in subgravity conditions there is a loss of muscle mass and bone mass in space. Because in the absence of gravity, no weight is applied to the back and leg muscles, therefore they begin to weaken and lose mass and without the practice of Astronauts can lose up to 20 percent of their muscle mass in 5-11 days. Beyond that, there is also a phenomenon of fluids moving from the muscles to the bones in the astronauts' bodies.
>
> In order to be able to maintain the health of our astronauts, we would like to investigate these phenomena with the help of simulations with information we know from research. This is where you come into the picture!
>
> In this task you will have to build a system that will accept initial conditions for the simulation:
>
> `simulation_days` - an integer type variable, indicating the duration of the stay in space
> `initial_bone_mass` - a decimal number type variable, indicating the initial bone mass
> `initial_muscle_mass` - a decimal number type variable, indicating the initial muscle mass
>
> and calculate the expected values for the final muscle mass and bone mass after the time spent in space. The output will be received in the following format (note that the values are up to 2 numbers after the decimal point):
>
> Final Muscle Mass: XX.XX kg and Final Bone Mass: XX.XX kg
>
> Finally we will use in our program the information we received from previous studies to make our simulation more accurate:
>
> Muscle mass decreases every day by 2% while staying in space
>
> Bone mass decreases every day by 1.5% while staying in space
>
> In addition, the fluids in the muscles leave them and move to the bones at a rate of 2% per day during the stay in space
>
> Successfully! trust you
>
> Example 1
>
> input:
>
> 4 - Duration of stay in space
>
> 40 - initial bone mass
>
> 60 - the initial muscle mass
>
> output:
>
> Final Muscle Mass: 51.05 kg and Final Bone Mass: 41.98 kg
>
> Example 2
>
> input:
>
> 30 - Duration of stay in space
>
> 50 - initial bone mass
>
> 50 - the initial muscle mass
>
> output:
>
> Final Muscle Mass: 14.88 kg and Final Bone Mass: 45.23 kg

I think it may be something with the accuracy or printing format

Comment: your formatting looks good to me.

Comment: You don't need the `+=` and `-=` calculations. You're already subtracting the appropriate amount of bone and muscle mass with the `*=` statements.

Comment: The `+=` and `-=` are for the third aspect: Fluids moving from muscles to bones.

Comment: Ah. You need to calculate how much will be moved *before* you reduce the mass. Put it in another variable. You don't need to subtract again from muscle.

Comment: `final_muscle_mass *= (1 - 0.02)` and `final_muscle_mass -= 0.02 * final_muscle_mass` seem to be one calculation too many.

Answer (score 0):

Save the amount of muscle mass that will be transferred to bones in another variable before you reduce the mass.

```
for day in range(simulation_days):
    muscle_reduction = final_muscle_mass * 0.02
    final_muscle_mass -= muscle_reduction 
    final_bone_mass *= (1 - 0.015)  
    final_bone_mass += muscle_reduction
```